# How to use geocube with option -at (all_touched=TRUE)

Tags: geocube

In the code below, I'm trying to rasterize "roads" and "cube" to  128x128 pixels with a 10m spatial resolution for each pixel. First, I want to rasterize roads separately to make them look better by using the option "all_touched"=True. And then I want to merge them to the same raster.

How do I use the option "all_touched=True"?

```
for idx,row in enumerate(clip.itertuples()):
    if row.code_2018 !=None:
        train_id[idx]=(class_dic[str(row.code_2018)]['train_id'])
    
clip = clip.assign(train_id=train_id)
roads=clip.code_2018.isin(['12210','12220','12230'])
roads = clip[roads]
cube  = make_geocube(
    vector_data=clip,
    measurements=['train_id'],
    resolution=(10,-10)
)
roads = make_geocube(
    vector_data=roads,
    measurements=['train_id'],
    resolution=(10,-10)
)
break
```

[image: [![want to merge these][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOUbu.png]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Bullet lists of questions will result in closure votes. Please [Edit] the Question to focus on your most pressing issue.

Answer (score 2):

You want to follow the pattern demonstrated here: https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/examples/rasterize_point_data.html

```py
from functools import partial
from geocube.rasterize import rasterize_image

roads = make_geocube(
    vector_data=roads,
    measurements=['train_id'],
    resolution=(10,-10),
    rasterize_function=partial(rasterize_image, all_touched=True),
)
```

Also see: https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/geocube.html#geocube.rasterize.rasterize_image

Comment: Thank you! Saviour of the day!